# kendo Datasource return custom value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a remote datasource like this,

```
var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    autoSync: false,
    batch: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "some_url",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverGrouping: true,
    serverPaging: false,
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 10,
    schema: {
        data: "results",
        total: "total",
        model: {
            id: "id"
        }
    }    
});
```

And I would like to get one additional value from the serverside like this.

```
    $response = array(
        'results' => $product_alerts,
        'total'   => $total,
        'total_approved_products'  => 27
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
```

Is there anyway I can get the value of total_approved_products in ClientSide ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative to @OnaBai's solution is following. Both solutions are not perfect however picking up the extra object on parse is dangerous in case you have implemented read/update/create/delete, their response objects will also hit parse and your total_approved_products will most likely not be there. I would suggest use the complete event on datasource read.

```
read: {
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: _op.serviceBaseUrl + "ReadX",
                    complete: function (jqXhr, textStatus) {
                            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXhr.responseText);
                            alert(result.d.total_approved_products);
                     }
        }
```

Comment: You say "dangerous"... I think that is pretty easy to solve adding  an _if_: `if (d.total_approved_products) alert(d.total_approved_products)`. Doesn't seem so "danger" and you save a lot of lines of code!

Answer (score 4):

Add to the `schema` definition a `parse` function where you extract `total_approved_products` and whatever you want with it. Example:

```
schema         : {
    data : "results",
    total: "total",
    model: {
        id: "id"
    },
    parse: function (d) {
        // Get total_approved_products and display alert.
        alert(d.total_approved_products);
        // Return data in order to be included in the `DataSource.data`
        return d;
    }
}
```