# Set callback function for kendo widget events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

There is no documentation that I can see for adding call backs after kendo ui widget code has fired. I have the following kendo ui widget declaration.

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date("2013/6/13"),    // Change this to current date with twig
    startTime: new Date("2013/6/13 07:00 AM"), // Change this to 12:00 AM of current date
    allDaySlot: false,
    width:600,
    height:500,
    resize: function(e) {
        if (careGiverIsOccupied(e.start, e.end, e.event, e.resources)) {
            this.wrapper.find(".k-marquee-color").addClass("invalid-slot");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    resizeEnd: function(e) {
        if (!checkAvailability(e.start, e.end, e.events)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    move: function(e) {
        if (careGiverIsOccupied(e.start, e.end, e.event, e.resources)) {
            this.wrapper.find(".k-event-drag-hint").addClass("invalid-slot");
        }
    },
    moveEnd: function(e) {
        if (!checkAvailability(e.start, e.end, e.event, e.resources)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    add: function(e) {
        if (!checkAvailability(e.event.start, e.event.end, e.event)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        changeColors();
    },
    save: function(e) {
        if (!checkAvailability(e.event.start, e.event.end, e.event)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        changeColors();
    },
    views: [
        "week",
        "month"
    ],
    dataSource: {
        data: [
            {
                eventID: 2,
                title: "Hey man",
                start: new Date("2013/6/13 12:00"),
                end: new Date("2013/6/13 13:30"),
                pending: true,
                permissionToDelete: false,
                careGiverId: 1
            },
            {
                eventID: 1,
                title: "Call Charlie about the project",
                start: new Date("2013/6/13 10:30"),
                end: new Date("2013/6/13 11:30"),
                pending: false,
                permissionToDelete: false,
                careGiverId: 1
            }
            ],
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "eventID",
                fields: {
                    eventID: { type: "number" },
                    title: { defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                    start: { type: "date" },
                    end: { type: "date" },
                    careGiverId: { nullable: true },
                    pending: { type: "boolean", defaultValue:true },
                    permissionToDelete: { type: "boolean", defaultValue:true },
                    isAllDay: { type: "boolean" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    group: {
        resources: [ "care" ]
    },
    resources: [
        {
            field: "careGiverId",
            name: "care",
            dataSource: [
                { 
                    // Change the text with care giver name, change value with care giver id
                    text: "Jeffery Dohmer (Care Giver 1)", value: 1, color: "#00FF00" 
                }
            ],
            title: "Care"
        }
    ]
});
```

The problem is that the dom structure of my document is modified after the event handlers like resizeEnd, move, moveEnd, add, and save have fired. What I would like to do is to change the color of a particular element after, the kendoScheduler has added or save the time. Is there anyway to add a callback after this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an elegant answer for this question. Apparently there is an event called dataBound: that allows one to fire a callback after everything has been done.

In my case I want to use:

```
dataBound: function(e){

    // Code after widget is finished processing everything

}
```

Comment: Your question was about "added or save", databound fires for other operations such as delete. Well anyway if it works it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the complete event example in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16570373/485790):

```
read: {
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: _op.serviceBaseUrl + "ReadX",
                complete: function () {
                      console.log('Tweak your UI here');
                 }
    }
```

Obviously the "complete" event is available only when you working with [remote data.](http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/use-the-datasource-component#creating-a-datasource-for-remote-data).

As well as, have a look at this `requestEnd` [event](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#events-requestEnd):

```
 requestEnd: function(e) {
    var response = e.response;
    var type = e.type;
    console.log(type); // displays "read"
    console.log(response.length); // displays "77"
  }
```

Use switch on `e.type` to distinguish in between different operations *(The type of the request. Set to "create", "read", "update" or "destroy".)*